# Inserting data into a database - org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column count does not match; SQL statement:

Tags: java, database, h2

I've been trying to save values into a database called "CLIENT".

The database is created via this code:

```
package Database;

//STEP 1. Import required packages
import java.sql.*;

public class JDBCExampleCreateTables {
    // JDBC driver name and database URL
    private static String JDBC_DRIVER = "org.h2.Driver";
    private static String DB_URL = "jdbc:h2:file:C:/WAKILI/WAKILIdb";

    //  Database credentials
    private static String USER = "sa";
    private static String PASS = "";

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;

        try {
            //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
            Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);

            //STEP 3: Open a connection
            System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database...");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
            System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");

            //STEP 4: Execute a query
            System.out.println("Creating table in given database...");
            stmt = conn.createStatement();

            String sql = "CREATE TABLE CLIENT " +
                    "(ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, " + 
                    " fullNames VARCHAR(255), " + 
                    " iDNumber VARCHAR(255), " + 
                    " pINNumber VARCHAR(255), " + 
                    " passportNumber VARCHAR(255), " + 
                    " postOfficeBoxNumber VARCHAR(255), " + 
                    " postalCode VARCHAR(255), " + 
                    " telephoneNumberLandline VARCHAR(255), " + 
                    " telephoneNumberMobile VARCHAR(255), " + 
                    " CARD VARCHAR(255)) "; 

            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
            System.out.println("Created table in given database...");

        } catch (SQLException se) {
            //Handle errors for JDBC
            se.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Handle errors for Class.forName
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // finally block used to close resources
            try {
                if (stmt!=null)
                    conn.close();
            } catch(SQLException se) {
            } // do nothing
            try {
                if (conn!=null)
                    conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException se) {
                se.printStackTrace();
            } // end finally try
        } // end try
        System.out.println("Goodbye!");
    } // end main
} // end
```

The class that I'm trying to have save into the database is:

```
package Database;

//STEP 1. Import required packages
import java.sql.*;

public class JDBCExampleInsertRecords {
    public final String values;
    public final String table;

    public JDBCExampleInsertRecords (String values, String table) 
    {
        this.values = values;
        this.table = table;
    }

    // JDBC driver name and database URL
    private static String JDBC_DRIVER = "org.h2.Driver";
    private static String DB_URL = "jdbc:h2:file:C:/WAKILI/WAKILIdb";

    //  Database credentials
    private static String USER = "sa";
    private static String PASS = "";

    public static void main () {
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;

        try {
            //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
            Class.forName(getJDBC_DRIVER());

            //STEP 3: Open a connection
            System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database...");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(getDB_URL(), getUSER(), getPASS());
            System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");

            //STEP 4: Execute a query
            System.out.println("Inserting records into the table...");
            stmt = conn.createStatement();

            String sql = "INSERT INTO CLIENT " + "VALUES ((values))";
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

            System.out.println("Inserted records into the table...");

        } catch (SQLException se) {
            //Handle errors for JDBC
            se.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Handle errors for Class.forName
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            //finally block used to close resources
            try {
                if (stmt != null)
                    conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException se) {
            } // do nothing
            try {
                if (conn!=null)
                    conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException se) {
                se.printStackTrace();
            } //end finally try
        } //end try

        System.out.println("Goodbye!");
    } //end main

    /**
     * @return the JDBC_DRIVER
     */
    public static String getJDBC_DRIVER() {
        return JDBC_DRIVER;
    }

    /**
     * @param aJDBC_DRIVER the JDBC_DRIVER to set
     */
    public static void setJDBC_DRIVER(String aJDBC_DRIVER) {
        JDBC_DRIVER = aJDBC_DRIVER;
    }

    /**
     * @return the DB_URL
     */
    public static String getDB_URL() {
        return DB_URL;
    }

    /**
     * @param aDB_URL the DB_URL to set
     */
    public static void setDB_URL(String aDB_URL) {
        DB_URL = aDB_URL;
    }

    /**
     * @return the USER
     */
    public static String getUSER() {
        return USER;
    }

    /**
     * @param aUSER the USER to set
     */
    public static void setUSER(String aUSER) {
        USER = aUSER;
    }

    /**
     * @return the PASS
     */
    public static String getPASS() {
        return PASS;
    }

    /**
     * @param aPASS the PASS to set
     */
    public static void setPASS(String aPASS) {
        PASS = aPASS;
    }
} //end
```

The code that gets the values is in a Class called "AddNewClient" and is as follows:

```
    public String getValues () {
    String fullNames = fullNamesJTextField.getText();
    String iDNumber = identificationNumberJTextField.getText();
    String pINNumber = pINNumberJTextField.getText();
    String passportNumber = passportNumberJTextField.getText();
    String postOfficeBoxNumber = postOfficeBoxNumberJTextField.getText();
    String postalCode = postalCodeJTextField.getText();
    String telephoneNumberLandline = telephoneNumberLandlineJTextField.getText();
    String telephoneNumberMobile = telephoneNumberMobileJTextField.getText();

    List<String> client = new ArrayList<String>();

    client.add(fullNames);
    client.add(iDNumber);
    client.add(pINNumber);
    client.add(passportNumber);
    client.add(postOfficeBoxNumber);
    client.add(postalCode);
    client.add(telephoneNumberLandline);
    client.add(telephoneNumberMobile);

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    String listStringClient = "";

    for (String s : client)
    {
        listStringClient += "NULL" + "'" + s + "'" + ",";
    }

    return listStringClient;
}
```

I get an error message:

```
run:
Connecting to a selected database...
Connected database successfully...
Inserting records into the table...
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column count does not match; SQL statement:
```

I've been at this for the past two days to no success whatsoever. I will be very, very very greatful to anyone who would come to my rescue. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where one problem is:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO CLIENT " + "VALUES ((values))";
stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

Values should be the getValues() method, instead of just a string, so

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO CLIENT VALUES (" + getValues() + ")";
```

Additionally, since you do not specify which columns, it is assumed that all columns are being entered in the values. If CARD does not have a default value in your SQL database, and if it cannot be NULL, you're going to have a problem.

Finally, this is a little strange:

```
for (String s : client)
{
    listStringClient += "NULL" + "'" + s + "'" + ",";
}
```

You'll want the values, not 'NULL', so it should be

```
for (String s : client)
{
    listStringClient += "'" + s + "'" + ",";
}
```

And finally, the way you're doing it, you're going to have an extra comma at the end (ex: 'value1','value2','value3',)

Clip the final comma:

```
return listStringClient.substring(0, listStringClient.size() - 1);
```

Granted, there's a better way to do the for loop where you do not have that extra comma.

End the end, the sql String should look like this:

```
"INSERT INTO CLIENT VALUES('value1','value2','value3','value4','value5','value6')"
```

Do a System.out.println(sql) and see what the String statement is that you're trying to execute. You'll see the error then.

Here's a better way to build your values string without the comma issue:

```
Iterator<String> iter = client.iterator();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

while (iter.hasNext()) {
    sb.append("'").append(iter.next()).append("'");
    if (iter.hasNext())
        sb.append(",");
}
return sb.toString();
```

Comment: I'm not an experienced programmer and I've been trying to teach myself how to program software. Would you mind teaching me how else I can do a for loop so that I get no comma?

Comment: I would use an Iterator, since while you iterate through your List, you can check to see if there will be a next value and add a comma. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

You do not pass any value in your statement. Following code is static, it does not have parameters:

```
INSERT INTO CLIENT " + "VALUES ((values))
```

It is nonsense SQL command: INSERT INTO CLIENT VALUES ((values)). You wanted express

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO CLIENT VALUES " + getValues()";
```

I prefer to use PreparedStatement, as it is safe and it will escape dangerous characters:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO PRODUCT VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement prest = con.prepareStatement(sql);
prest.setString(1, "asdf");
prest.setInt(2, 2009);
// etc
int count = prest.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 1):

You forget to mention the value for `CARD` column. If you dont want to set any value there, just pass `' '`.

Your `for` loop should be like this

```
for (String s : client)
{
    listStringClient += "NULL" + "'" + s + "'" + ",";//GIVES YOU ERROR BECAUSE AT THE END OF
}                                               // FOR LOOP IT HAS , IN THE END OF STRING.
 listStringClient+="' '";//This is for CARD COLUMN.
```

Answer (score 1):

I think instead of :

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO CLIENT " + "VALUES ((values))";
```

You want something like :

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO CLIENT " + "VALUES ("+getValues()+")";
```

Also the implementation of `getValues` is kind of strange :

```
for (String s : client)
{
    listStringClient += "NULL" + "'" + s + "'" + ",";
}
```

Probably it could be :

```
for (String s : client)
{
    listStringClient += "'" + s + "',"
}
listStringClient += "NULL";
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't thank you all enough for the amazing answers. I put the various ideas and came up with this solution to my problem.

My working answer to my Question above takes ideas from Leos Literak, abmitchell, Vimal Bera and Grisha's answers.

The database is created via this code:

```
package Database;

//STEP 1. Import required packages
import java.sql.*;

public class JDBCExampleCreateTables {
    // JDBC driver name and database URL
    private static String JDBC_DRIVER = "org.h2.Driver";
    private static String DB_URL = "jdbc:h2:file:C:/WAKILI/WAKILIdb";

    //  Database credentials
    private static String USER = "sa";
    private static String PASS = "";

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;

        try {
            //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
            Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);

            //STEP 3: Open a connection
            System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database...");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
            System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");

            //STEP 4: Execute a query
            System.out.println("Creating table in given database...");
            stmt = conn.createStatement();

            String sql = "CREATE TABLE CLIENT " +
                    "(ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, " + 
                    " fullNames VARCHAR(255), " + 
                    " iDNumber VARCHAR(255), " + 
                    " pINNumber VARCHAR(255), " + 
                    " passportNumber VARCHAR(255), " + 
                    " postOfficeBoxNumber VARCHAR(255), " + 
                    " postalCode VARCHAR(255), " + 
                    " telephoneNumberLandline VARCHAR(255), " + 
                    " telephoneNumberMobile VARCHAR(255)) "; 

            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
            System.out.println("Created table in given database...");

        } catch (SQLException se) {
            //Handle errors for JDBC
            se.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Handle errors for Class.forName
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // finally block used to close resources
            try {
                if (stmt!=null)
                    conn.close();
            } catch(SQLException se) {
            } // do nothing
            try {
                if (conn!=null)
                    conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException se) {
                se.printStackTrace();
            } // end finally try
        } // end try
        System.out.println("Goodbye!");
    } // end main
} // end
```

The class that saves into the database is:

```
package Database;

//STEP 1. Import required packages
import java.sql.*;

public class JDBCExampleInsertRecords {
    public static String values;
    public final String table;

    public JDBCExampleInsertRecords (String values, String table) 
    {
        this.values = values;
        this.table = table;
    }

    // JDBC driver name and database URL
    private static String JDBC_DRIVER = "org.h2.Driver";
    private static String DB_URL = "jdbc:h2:file:C:/WAKILI/WAKILIdb";

    //  Database credentials
    private static String USER = "sa";
    private static String PASS = "";

    public static void main () {
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;

        try {
            //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
            Class.forName(getJDBC_DRIVER());

            //STEP 3: Open a connection
            System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database...");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(getDB_URL(), getUSER(), getPASS());
            System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");

            //STEP 4: Execute a query
            System.out.println("Inserting records into the table...");
            stmt = conn.createStatement();

            String sql = "INSERT INTO CLIENT VALUES (NULL, " + (values) + ")";

            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

            System.out.println("Inserted records into the table...");

        } catch (SQLException se) {
            //Handle errors for JDBC
            se.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Handle errors for Class.forName
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            //finally block used to close resources
            try {
                if (stmt != null)
                    conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException se) {
            } // do nothing
            try {
                if (conn!=null)
                    conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException se) {
                se.printStackTrace();
            } //end finally try
        } //end try

        System.out.println("Goodbye!");
    } //end main

    /**
     * @return the JDBC_DRIVER
     */
    public static String getJDBC_DRIVER() {
        return JDBC_DRIVER;
    }

    /**
     * @param aJDBC_DRIVER the JDBC_DRIVER to set
     */
    public static void setJDBC_DRIVER(String aJDBC_DRIVER) {
        JDBC_DRIVER = aJDBC_DRIVER;
    }

    /**
     * @return the DB_URL
     */
    public static String getDB_URL() {
        return DB_URL;
    }

    /**
     * @param aDB_URL the DB_URL to set
     */
    public static void setDB_URL(String aDB_URL) {
        DB_URL = aDB_URL;
    }

    /**
     * @return the USER
     */
    public static String getUSER() {
        return USER;
    }

    /**
     * @param aUSER the USER to set
     */
    public static void setUSER(String aUSER) {
        USER = aUSER;
    }

    /**
     * @return the PASS
     */
    public static String getPASS() {
        return PASS;
    }

    /**
     * @param aPASS the PASS to set
     */
    public static void setPASS(String aPASS) {
        PASS = aPASS;
    }
} //end
```

The code that gets the values is in a Class called "AddNewClient" and is as follows:

```
    public String getValues () {
    String fullNames = fullNamesJTextField.getText();
    String iDNumber = identificationNumberJTextField.getText();
    String pINNumber = pINNumberJTextField.getText();
    String passportNumber = passportNumberJTextField.getText();
    String postOfficeBoxNumber = postOfficeBoxNumberJTextField.getText();
    String postalCode = postalCodeJTextField.getText();
    String telephoneNumberLandline = telephoneNumberLandlineJTextField.getText();
    String telephoneNumberMobile = telephoneNumberMobileJTextField.getText();

    List<String> client = new ArrayList<String>();

    client.add(fullNames);
    client.add(iDNumber);
    client.add(pINNumber);
    client.add(passportNumber);
    client.add(postOfficeBoxNumber);
    client.add(postalCode);
    client.add(telephoneNumberLandline);
    client.add(telephoneNumberMobile);

    Iterator<String> iter = client.iterator();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        sb.append("'").append(iter.next()).append("'");
        if (iter.hasNext())
            sb.append(",");
    }

    return sb.toString();
    }
```